# Enabling make to expand on user-supplied macro

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to convince make to accept a user-supplied macro and then expand on it?  One simple example of what I mean is that I would like the user to be able to issue:

```
> make CFLAGS='-g'
```

and then somewhere in `Makefile` would be a line like:

```
CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -O2
```

so that, altogether `CFLAGS` would evaluate to `-g -O2`.  AFAICT, if the user issues that command, `make` takes `CFLAGS` as `-g` and won't touch it further.  Of course, I could have the user issue something like

```
> make CFIN='-g'
```

and then in the Makefile put

```
CFLAGS := $(CFIN) -O2
```

but that just seems a bit "clunky" to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
CFLAGS :=
override CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -O2
```

The first assignment prevents the contents of `CFLAGS` environment variable from being imported as the Make variable with the same name. If you want this behavior, remove the first line.